# JavaFX: ObsevableMap keySet as an ObservableSet

Tags: java-8, javafx-8

I want to transform an ObservableMap's keySet to a read only ObservableSet. I don't want to copy the value, any modification to the ObservableMap must affect the Observable keySet. If i bind another set to the observable key set content, its content is automatically updated.

This is what i would like to write.

```
ObservableMap<String, Object> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
ObservableSet<String> keySet = FXCollections.observableKeySet(map);
Set<String> boundSet = new HashSet<String>();
Bindings.bindContent(boundSet, keySet);
map.put("v", new Object());
assert boundSet.contains("v");
```

Is there this functionality in the JavaFX SDK ?

Answer (score 1):

The feature you request does not need a special `ObservableSet`. It’s already part of the `Map` interface contract:

```
ObservableMap<String, Object> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
map.put("v", new Object());
assert keySet.contains("v");
```

A `Map`’s keyset always reflects the changes made to the backing map.

<sub>http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--</sub>

> Returns a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks @Holger. I am sorry my question wasn't specific enough. I really need an `ObservableSet` i have updated my answer.

Comment: @gontard: It’s still not clear why you need an `ObservableSet`. Your `boundSet` doesn’t offer any additional feature compared to the `keySet` in my answer. Should I rename `keySet` to `boundSet` to make you feel more comfortable?

Comment: The problem is that the keySet of `Map` is not observable in the JavaFX sense. We can't attach event listeners to the keyset retrieved from the ObservableMap, nor can we bind its elements to a ListView for instance. This question is very JavaFX specific..

Comment: @Joffrey: that might be your problem, but wasn’t the problem shown in this question. In this question, the `ObservableSet` was bound to a `HashSet`, which would result in a behavior, the `keySet()` of the `ObservableMap` already provides on its own. If you want to bind the set to list view, you have a different question.

Comment: Well it was in the question, since OP tried to bind the returned `keySet` from the map. What makes you think OP controls the bound `HashSet`? If he wants to bind another collection to the `keySet` he gets, it's most likely because he doesn't control that destination collection because it is an internal property of some other class, which is probably the problem every reader of this question would have. Of course, that's my interpretation of the question, but I guess the OP would have accepted your answer if he actually could get rid of the extra boundSet.

Comment: @Joffrey: the OP had two years to name additional requirements or use cases, so I don’t see any point in reinterpreting the question now. Feel free to add another answer, if you think, it’s worth it.

Comment: Well he already explained once, and then I think he just gave up. I didn't find any built-in solution to do this unfortunately, and I ended up working around it with custom listeners that don't achieve the exact "observable keyset" functionality, so it's not relevant here as an answer. I guess future readers will have to implement their own listeners too.

Comment: @Joffrey: Under your assumption regarding the question’s goal, I don’t see why your comment “*I didn't find any built-in solution to do this … future readers will have to implement their own listeners too*.” is not an answer.

Comment: I'll agree with Holger that the above solution does create a set that reflects the map's keys as they are updated. I'll agree with Joffrey that after the OP updated the question, this solution no longer meets his use case since he now wants to be able to create a binding with it. I had the same need, so I'll post my solution as an answer as well even though this question is super old.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no built-in way to do it.

Here's a utility method that I made to handle this:

```java
    /**
     * Builds and returns an observable keyset of the specified map. Note that the resulting
     * keyset is a new set that is guaranteed to have the same items as the map's true
     * keyset, but does not make any guarantees about iteration order or implementation
     * details of the keyset (for example, if the Map is a SortedMap, the keyset 
     * will not necessarily maintain keys in sorted order).
     * @param <K> Map's key type
     * @param <V> Map's value type
     * @param map the ObservableMap to which the set should be bound
     * @return a new observable set reflecting the map's keys 
     */
    public static <K, V> ObservableSet<K> getObservableKeySet(ObservableMap<K, V> map) {
        
        ObservableSet<K> set = FXCollections.observableSet(new HashSet<>());
        
        map.addListener(
                (MapChangeListener<K, V>)(
                        change -> {
                            if(change.wasAdded() && !change.wasRemoved()) {
                                set.add(change.getKey());
                            }
                            if(change.wasRemoved() && !change.wasAdded()) {
                                set.remove(change.getKey());
                            }
                            //Note that if change was added and removed, that means that
                            //the key was unchanged and a value was just replaced. That
                            //shouldn't affect the keyset so we do nothing
                            
                        })
                );
        
        return set;
        
    }
```

Update:

I decided that I didn't like how the iteration order of the resulting set wouldn't match the original map's iteration order, so instead I made a new class that acts as an observable wrapper around a map's keyset. This is more like Map's built-in keySet() method where it returns a view of the actual set. This just adds in the listeners that make it observable:

```java
/**
 * Observable view of an ObservableMap's keyset
 */
public class ObservableKeySet<K, V> implements ObservableSet<K> {

    /**
     * The map's actual keyset object that gets wrapped
     */
    private Set<K> wrappedSet;
    
    /**
     * Invalidation listeners to be notified when the set changes. Note that we end 
     * up calling these more than we should since invalidation listeners should only 
     * be called if the observable value is observed between changes and we're going 
     * to call them on every change. However, the ObservableSet returned from 
     * FxCollectionUtilities.observableSet actually also does that too, so I feel 
     * like we can get away with it.
     */
    private Collection<InvalidationListener> invalidationListeners = new ArrayList<>();
    
    /**
     * Change listeners to be notified when the set changes
     */
    private Collection<SetChangeListener<? super K>> changeListeners = new ArrayList<>();
    
    /**
     * Creates an Observable Set view of the specified map's keyset
     * @param map ObservableMap
     */
    public ObservableKeySet(ObservableMap<K, V> map) {
        this.wrappedSet = map.keySet();
        
        map.addListener((MapChangeListener<K,V>)this::onMapChange);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Code to be executed on any match change. It will determine if there is a resulting
     * set change and trigger listeners as appropriate
     * @param change
     */
    private void onMapChange(MapChangeListener.Change<? extends K, ? extends V> change) {
        
        SetChangeListener.Change<K> setChange = null;
        
        //Note that if the map change says that there was an add and removal, then
        //that means a value was getting replaced, which doesn't result in a keySet
        //change
        if(change.wasAdded() && ! change.wasRemoved()) {
            setChange = new BasicSetChange(true, change.getKey());
        }
        else if(change.wasRemoved() && ! change.wasAdded()) {
            setChange = new BasicSetChange(false, change.getKey());
        }
        
        if(setChange != null) {
            
            invalidationListeners.forEach(listener -> listener.invalidated(this));
            
            final SetChangeListener.Change<K> finalChange = setChange;
            changeListeners.forEach(listener -> listener.onChanged(finalChange));
        }
        
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
        invalidationListeners.add(listener);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
        invalidationListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(SetChangeListener<? super K> listener) {
        changeListeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(SetChangeListener<? super K> listener) {
        changeListeners.remove(listener);
    }
    
    //Simple wrapper method that either just pass through to the wrapped set or 
    //throw an unsupported operation exception
    @Override public int size() {return wrappedSet.size();}
    @Override public boolean isEmpty() {return wrappedSet.isEmpty();}
    @Override public boolean contains(Object o) {return wrappedSet.contains(o);}
    @Override public Iterator<K> iterator() {return wrappedSet.iterator();}
    @Override public Object[] toArray() {return wrappedSet.toArray();}
    @Override public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {return wrappedSet.toArray(a);}
    @Override public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {return wrappedSet.containsAll(c);}
    
    @Override public boolean add(K e) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    @Override public boolean remove(Object o) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    @Override public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends K> c) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    @Override public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    @Override public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    @Override public void clear() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    
    
    /**
     * Simple implementation of {@link SetChangeListener.Change}
     */
    private class BasicSetChange extends SetChangeListener.Change<K> {
        
        /** If true, it is an add change, otherwise it is a remove change*/
        private final boolean isAdd;
        
        /** Value that was added or removed */
        private final K value;
        
        /**
         * @param isAdd {@link #isAdd}
         * @param value {@link #value}
         */
        public BasicSetChange(boolean isAdd, K value) {
            super(ObservableKeySet.this);
            this.isAdd = isAdd;
            this.value = value;
        }
        

        @Override
        public boolean wasAdded() {
            return isAdd;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean wasRemoved() {
            return !isAdd;
        }

        @Override
        public K getElementAdded() {
            return isAdd ? value : null;
        }

        @Override
        public K getElementRemoved() {
            return isAdd ? null : value;
        }
    }

}
```